# Call ant target multiple times with different parameters

Tags: ant

Is it possible in Ant to call the same target multiple times with different parameters?

My command looks like the following:

```
ant unittest -Dproject='proj1' unittest -Dproject='proj2'
```

The problem is that unittest gets run twice, but only for proj2:

```
unittest:
    [echo] Executing unit test for project proj2

unittest:
    [echo] Executing unit test for project proj2
```

I know that I can run two separate ant commands, but that is going to cause additional problems with the unit test report files.

Comment: In the same command line, you define the property `-Dproject`multiple times. The effect is that only the last definition will be used, since it overwrites any previous definition. It's the same thing as for the Java command line.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You could add another target to invoke your unittest target twice, with different parameters, using the [antcall](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) task e.g.

```
<project name="test" default="test">

    <target name="test">
        <antcall target="unittest">
            <param name="project" value="proj1"/>
        </antcall>
        <antcall target="unittest">
            <param name="project" value="proj2"/>
        </antcall>
    </target>

    <target name="unittest">
        <echo message="project=${project}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Output:

```
test:

unittest:
     [echo] project=proj1

unittest:
     [echo] project=proj2

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

Alternatively, you could change the unittest target to be a [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html):

```
<project name="test" default="test">

    <target name="test">
        <unittest project="proj1"/>
        <unittest project="proj2"/>
    </target>

    <macrodef name="unittest">
        <attribute name="project"/>
        <sequential>
            <echo message="project=@{project}"/>
        </sequential>
    </macrodef>

</project>
```

Comment: Antcall should be avoided because of it's well known drawbacks => use macrodef instead !

Comment: will it work If I try to have dynamic value for param?
<param name="project" value="${project1}"/>

Comment: Any luck with that @hariszaman? I'm looking for similar thing in combination with `for` tag.

Comment: I will check it out it was a long time i did this